# Java чтение и запись none-blocked

Tags: java, файлы

Мне нужен способ чтение и записи в файл с использованием указателя.
То есть что бы я мог поставить указатель на нужную мне позицию в файле и считать или записать определенное колличество байт.
Так же прошу заметить что все это делается в многопоточном режиме.
Мне нужен максимально подходящий и оптимизированный инструмент под данную ситуацию

Comment: Используйте [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), а синхронизацию делайте под свою задачу с помощью интерфейса `Lock` и его потомков.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть специальный класс RandomAccessFile. Метод seek() позволяет указать позицию в файле куда нужно записывать.

Comment: но как мне сделать асинхранизацию мне бы что нибудь подобное только nio

Comment: С помощью синхронизации потоков, доступ к файлу синхронизирован будет

Comment: @CloolMear что такое "асинхронизация"?

Comment: @Sergey_Gornostaev Имелось ввиду что бы при записи или чтении поток не блокировался. Это же даст большой прирост к производительности разве нет

Comment: Так вы можете и не блокировать, просто всегда нужно следить за индексом записи в файл

Comment: всм можете не блокировать разве все что java.io не блокируется сама при записи или выводе

Comment: Вот ответ:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882168/java-thread-safe-randomaccessfile

Comment: @CloolMear тогда это называется "асинхронность". Асинхронно читать файлы можно с помощью [AsynchronousFileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html), но в многопоточной среде толку от этого мало.